# Identifier required when invoking a private method

Tags: java

I am calling a private method for testing and for that I am using the following code to invoke private method. repeat() is the private method of class Diamond

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class DiamondUnit {
        StringBuilder expect = new StringBuilder();
        Diamond test = new Diamond();
        Method m = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("repeat");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(test);

    @Test
        public void testRepeatNeg() {
            assertEquals("", test.repeat(expect,"a",-1));
        }
}
```

While compiling it is giving error

```
DiamondUnit.java:11: error: expected
m.setAccessible(true);
^
DiamondUnit.java:11: error: illegal start of type
m.setAccessible(true);
^
DiamondUnit.java:12: error: expected
m.invoke(test);
^
DiamondUnit.java:12: error: expected
m.invoke(test);
^
```

I had cop pasted the exact error message which I am getting

Comment: Could you show us a minimal but complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: A little code is worth a lot of description. You might want to add the actual code that is showing the compiler errors.

Comment: Show us a minimal, self-contained complete example showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have statements outside of a method block. Put the code into an appropriate  method.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junt.SetUp;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class DiamondUnit {
    public void method() {
        StringBuilder expect = new StringBuilder();
        Diamond test = new Diamond();
        Method m = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("repeat");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(test);
    }

    @Test
        public void testRepeatNeg() {
            assertEquals("", test.repeat(expect,"a",-1));
        }
}
```

Comment: You answer would be improved if you illustrated how to refactor the code in such a way as his test would actually work.

Comment: Probably. Unfortunately I have no clue what kind of method should contain the runaway code - a test method, a setup method. And it is not really clear from the code.